# How do I pass arguments to a defined function in a shell script?

Tags: bash, terminal, sh

I'm trying to create a function wherein I pass two dates as arguments and get their day of the week out. I've gotten it to work by copying and pasting the parsing process for both input dates, but I'm trying to save space by condensing the process into a defined function. The input should look like so:

```
datematch.sh 01/03/1984 06/12/2008
```

But I keep getting error messages along the lines of:

```
./birthday_match.sh: line 9: ${$1:0:2}: bad substitution
./birthday_match.sh: line 9: ${$1:0:2}: bad substitution
The first person was born on: 
The second person was born on: 
Thus, they were born on the same day.
```

How am I substituting wrong? The full code is below.

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$1
var2=$2
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "illegal number of birthdays"
else
    function get_dayname () 
    {
        mo=${$1:0:2}
        dy=${$1:3:2}
        yr=${$1:6:4}
        combo="${mo}${dy}0000${yr}"
        fulldate="$(date $combo 2> /dev/null)"
        wkdy=${fulldate:0:3}
        eval $wkdy
    }
    first=$(get_dayname "$var1")
    second=$(get_dayname "$var2")
    echo "The first person was born on: $first"
    echo "The second person was born on: $second"
    if [ "$first" == "$second" ]; then
        echo "Thus, they were born on the same day."
    else
        echo "Thus, they were not born on the same day."
    fi
fi
```

Comment: It's `${1:0:2}`. The error is the extra `$`

Comment: Also, why are you using `eval`? You probably want `echo "$wkdy".

Answer (score 2):

The parameter expansion syntax is incorrect:

```
mo=${$1:0:2}
```

should be

```
mo=${1:0:2}
```

Consider the simple case.  Substituting the first argument as-is is either `$1` or `${1}`.   In the second version, the curly brackets serve to separate the variable name or number from what follows.

If you wrote `${$1}`, the intuitive meaning would be "treat the first argument as a name, and substitute the value of the variable with *that* name" .... but bash parameter expansion syntax doesn't allow that.